# sstableloader remote bulk upload

Tags: cassandra, datastax, k8ssandra

I'm trying to figure out how to upload data from a snapshot and why I'm getting this error on the bulk upload.
The local machine is trying to connect to cassandra.mydomain.com. The cassandra.yaml is the yaml from the remote server. I'm getting the same error with and without specifying --conf-path

Thanks for any advice.
cassandra version 3.11.2

```
~/deploy/cassandra/bin/sstableloader -d cassandra.mydomain.com --conf-path /tmp/cassandra.yaml /local/.data/cassandra/data/test/timeserie_time_daily-dd247b092e883bffbfce8621eff3cc3e/snapshots/1634621703263
        
10:10:50.138 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.config.YamlConfigurationLoader - Loading settings from file:/tmp/cassandra.yaml    
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. Found[cassandra.yaml]. Please prefix the file with [file:///] for local files and [file://<server>/] for remote file
            s. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
                    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:80)
                    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:100)
                    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:262)
                    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.toolInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:180)
                    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.toolInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:151)
                    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:53)
                    at o
    
    rg.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:48)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the exception states, you need to provide the correct URL to the `cassandra.yaml`.

If you're using a YAML that's on the local machine, you need to prefix it with `file:///`. For example:

```
$ sstableloader -f file:///path/to/cassandra.yaml
    -d node1
    ks_name/table_name
```

If you're specifying a YAML that's on a remote machine, you need to prefix it with `file://host/`. For example:

```
$ sstableloader -f file://hostname_or_ip/path/to/cassandra.yaml
    -d node1
    ks_name/table_name
```

Comment: no luck: ~/deploy/cassandra/bin/sstableloader -d cassandra.mydomain.com -f file:///tmp/cassandra.yaml /local/.data/cassandra/data/test/timeserie_time_daily-dd247b092e883bffbfce8621eff3cc3e/snapshots/1634621703263
Config file not found